# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined at CardList.js:11**

```js
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import Card from './Card';
    import {API_URL, API_KEY, IMAGE_BASE_URL} from './Config';

    function CardList() {
        const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
            const endpoint = `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;

            fetch(endpoint)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => console.log(response.results))
                .then(response => setMovies([response.results]))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }, [])

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    Movies && Movies.map((movie, i) => {
                        <Card
                            key={i}
                            image={movie.poster_path
                                ? `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}w500${movie.poster_path}`
                                : null}
                            title={movie.original_title}/>

                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default CardList;
```

I don't know why `console.log(response.results)` result is

```
Array(20)
0: {adult: false, backdrop_path: "/9yBVqNruk6Ykrwc32qrK2TIE5xw.jpg", genre_ids: Array(4), id: 460465, original_language: "en", …}
1: ...
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your error is coming from this line

```js
.then(response => setMovies([response.results]))
```

and is caused by the line above

```js
.then(response => console.log(response.results))
```

because you aren't returning the response object data for the next `.then()`. `console.log` doesn't return anything when called so in `setMovies([response.results])`, `response` is undefined when you try using it to set state.

I believe removing that line *should* solve this problem. If you want to keep the `console.log` call then I would put

```js
fetch(endpoint)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.results);
                    setMovies([response.results]);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the Array object with `console.log(response.results)`.
To print out just the contents of the array, try using the spread operator like this `console.log([...response.results])`